# How to call a React class method in redux connect mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

I am using redux, what I want is to **call a function before dispatching any action to the reducer**.
And one more thing is I don't want to take class methods outside of class.

I tried googling, everywhere they are simply dispatching an action.
I think I may miss some basic understanding, Could anyone of you please suggest how to proceed?

Below is my code:

```
class UltimateConsoleFunctionality extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  spinReels = function() {
    gsap.from(".Reels-row-symbols", 0.15, {
      y: "-=500",
      repeat: 10,
      ease: Linear.easeNone,
      onComplete: this.stopReels
    });
  };

  stopReels = function() {
    gsap.set(".Reels-row-symbols", { x: 0, y: 0 });
  };

  render() {
    switch (this.props.type) {
      case "spinStop":
        if (this.props.spin && !this.props.stop) {
          return (
            <div className="Ultimate-console-functionality">
              <img
                alt="spinButton"
                src={spinButton}
                onClick={this.props.spinReels}
                className="spinStop"
              />
            </div>
          );
        } else if (!this.props.spin && this.props.stop) {
          return (
            <div className="Ultimate-console-functionality">
              <img
                alt="stopButton"
                src={stopButton}
                onClick={this.props.stopReels}
                className="spinStop"
              />
            </div>
          );
        } else if (!this.props.spin && !this.props.stop) {
          return (
            <div className="Ultimate-console-functionality">QuickSpinMode</div>
          );
        }

        break;
      case "quickSpin":
        return (
          <div className="Ultimate-console-functionality">
            {this.props.quickSpin ? (
              <img
                alt="quickSpin"
                src={quickSpinSelected}
                onClick={this.props.quickSpinMethod}
                className="spinStop"
              />
            ) : (
              <img
                alt="stopButton"
                src={quickSpin}
                onClick={this.props.quickSpinMethod}
                className="spinStop"
              />
            )}
          </div>
        );
        break;
      default:
        return <div className="Ultimate-console-functionality">OTHERS</div>;
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    spin: state.spin,
    stop: state.stop,
    quickSpin: state.quickSpin
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    spinReels: () => {
      // How to call my class below method here
      UltimateConsoleFunctionality.spinReels();
      dispatch({ type: "SPIN" });
    },
    stopReels: () => {
      // How to call my class below method here
      UltimateConsoleFunctionality.stopReels();
      dispatch({ type: "STOP" });
    },
    quickSpinMethod: () => {
      dispatch({ type: "QUICKSPIN" });
    }
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(UltimateConsoleFunctionality);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `UltimateConsoleFunctionality.spinReels()` on the Object, not the instance. That's why it's not working in your case.

You can change your `onClick` attribute so it calls the `spinReels()` function in that instance:

```js
<img
    alt="spinButton"
    src={spinButton}
    onClick={() => {
        this.spinReels()
        this.props.spinReels()
    }} 
    className="spinStop"
/>
```

In that case, you need to change the `mapDispatchToProps()`' `spinReels()` binding to this:

```js
spinReels: () => {
    dispatch({ type: "SPIN" });
}
```

Your method names are really confusing though, I'd suggest changing them. Right now, in your `onClick`, you're first calling your Object's implementation of `spinReels()` (with `this.spinReels()`). Then, you're calling the `spinReels()` function in your `mapDispatchToProps()` (with `this.props.spinReels()`) which dispatches an action to Redux. You should definitely change the method names so it's clear which one is a dispatcher and which one is an object method.

Comment: thanks, Just want to know if there is any better way or any other way to do this?

Comment: Agree with the method names, also @sandeepKumar if you're using Redux and not using a localised state in the file I'd recommend changing it from a Class-based component to a functional-based one out of preference :)

Comment: @sandeepKumar Well you can use React in a number of different ways, my personal experience is that functional components and local state are a lot easier to understand when you're starting out. If you only need state within one component I'd suggest using local state instead of Redux. By the looks of it, you can refactor your conditional rendering to a version that's much more compact. Have a look here: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator